# Adding direction arrows to MKPolyline

Tags: mkmapview, core-graphics, mkpolyline

I'm trying to add direction arrows to a MKPolyline, and I've almost got it, but for some reason some of the arrows are chopped off (see screen shot below). I'm not great at drawing with Core Graphics, so my guess is it's something in there. Anyone have any pointers on how to deal with the clipped arrows?
[image: MKPolyline arrows]

The following code does the drawing from in the `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` method of a subclassed MKPolylineRenderer:

```
  MKMapPoint prevMapPoint = mapPoints[0];
  MKMapPoint mapPoint = mapPoints[1];
  for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < pointCount; i++) {
    mapPoint = _mapPoints[i];
    CGPoint prevCGPt = [self pointForMapPoint:prevMapPoint];
    CGPoint cgPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];
    CGFloat bearing = atan2(cgPoint.y - prevCGPt.y, cgPoint.x - prevCGPt.x) - M_PI;

    //Get other two corners of triangle
    CGFloat arrowAngle = degreesToRadians(40.0);
    CGPoint pt2 = PointAtBearingFromPoint(cgPoint, bearing+arrowAngle/2, arrowLength);
    CGPoint pt3 = PointAtBearingFromPoint(cgPoint, bearing-arrowAngle/2, arrowLength);

    //Draw triangle and fill
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cgPoint.x, cgPoint.y); //go to tip of triangle
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pt2.x, pt2.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pt3.x, pt3.y);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
  }

  prevMapPoint = mapPoint;
```

(also in the `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` method is a For loop to decide where to put each arrow and populate the mapPoints array, but I'm assuming that isn't the problem).

Comment: Wow, looks great! Very cool. — Yes, you are drawing in a context here (`context`). My guess is that for some values of your points you are partially drawing outside the context bounds. Well, that will clip the drawing. It should be easy to prove this; just do a little logging.

Comment: @matt Thanks. Looks like you're right. I put the drawing piece in an IF statement to see if any of the triangle's corners are outside the context, and that cut out the clipped arrows. The context I'm using is the one passed by `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` , so is there another context I should be using?

Comment: Sure, I would say just make your own image context and draw the arrow. Now you have a UIImage. Now draw that into place (in the original `context`).

Comment: In fact, may I add that I think the way you are drawing this thing is a little nutty. Instead of applying trig to the three points, why don't you just have one arrow image on hand all the time? Now you can just rotate it into place as you draw it into the polyline context.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know Core Graphics all that well. My impression was that drawing the lines would be quicker than loading an image several times over.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "load". I'm suggesting you draw the image in code and keep it around and just use it over and over (and over and over)... But even if you didn't want to do that, you could still be using the context's CTM to do the rotation rather than using trig.

Comment: Okay, I interpreted that wrong. Thought you meant loading an image from file. As for the previous point... I'm working on it now. I'll let you know how it goes :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125758/discussion-between-guthook-and-matt).

Comment: Do you have the code for PointAtBearingFromPoint?

Comment: @CamQuest check out this page-- lots of very useful calculation tools: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html  (for the bearing calculation, search for "LatLon.prototype.destinationPoint")

Comment: hi guthook, can you share please PointAtBearingFromPoint?

Comment: I too would very much benefit from a slightly more detailed sharing of code.